# Android input components return empty values

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have this small project with a few input components of which values i am trying to get on certain button click. The EditText values always return empty and the ToggleButton values - default false. What am I missing here? I emitted most of the styling for the sake of shortness.

fragment_addnewitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/addNewItemFragment"
tools:context=".controller.AddNewItemFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_addnewitem">

<EditText
    ...
    android:id="@+id/itemNameInput"
    android:inputType="text"
    .../>

 <Button
    ...
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    android:onClick="saveItem"
    android:text="SAVE"
    .../>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_addnewitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/addNewItem"
tools:context=".controller.AddNewItem">

<include layout="@layout/fragment_addnewitem" />

</FrameLayout>
```

AddNewItemFragment.java:

```
public class AddNewItemFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addnewitem, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

AddNewItemActivity.java:

```
public class AddNewItem extends AppCompatActivity {

private Item item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Item item = new Item();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addnewitem);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.addNewItemFragment, new AddNewItemFragment()).commit();
    }

public void saveItem(View view) {
    //empty
    item.setName(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemNameInput)).getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Of course I have more components setup but they are pretty much the same from code perspective. I have also got a date picker setup with an OnDateSetListener and that one works as expected. But none of the EditText or ToggleButton change their values.

Comment: In your activity's `onCreate()` you write `Item item = new Item()`. While I see no code that uses this `Item`, it shadows your activity's `item` instance field... is it possible that this is causing some problem in omitted code?

Comment: How do you check that the value of the input text is empty. Did you put a breakpoint in `saveItem`?

Comment: Where is R.id.addNewItemFragment ?

Comment: The instance shadowing is not the case here, since i've got a breakpoint on saveItem method and inspecting the EditText's value returns empty string all the time. @RaffaeleD'Arco R.id.addNewItemFragment is in the file at the very top (fragment_addnewitem.xml).

Answer (score 0):

After **super()**, inside **onCreate()**, you have created another Item object with the same name as the field Item. This is shadowing. Then that Item object is created before **setContentView()**.

I have made some changes to your class:

```
public class AddNewItem extends AppCompatActivity {
 private Item item; 
@Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_addnewitem); 
item = new Item();
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.addNewItemFragment, new AddNewItemFragment())
.commit();
}
}
public void saveItem(View view) {
//empty
item.setName(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemNameInput)).getText().toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case here. Putting a breakpoint on saveItem() and inspecting the EditText value always returns empty string.

Comment: Then create the editText object as a field variable. Then call saveItem() in a button click

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but the following lines were causing the problem with EditTexts:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.addNewItemFragment, new AddNewItemFragment()).commit();
}
```

Removed them and EditTexts now work as expected, but my Spinner which i populate on Fragement is not populated anymore and ToggleButtons always return false (isSelected()).